# SSH forwarding with wayland host and x11 client

Tags: ssh, xorg, wayland

OS: Ubuntu 21.10

I have a host computer running Wayland.

Client running gnome X11 session. I remote ssh to host **ssh -Y host**

running simple remote application like **xterm** on the client works, but other applications like **nautilus** or **gnome-terminal** are not. Is there a way to fix that. I thought that you do not need to run a window manager of any kind in order to forward application to a client running X11.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to set this up and test it out, but from reading some info that is out there about the forwarding from Wayland through ssh you will need a nested Xserver (Xephyr is one they mentioned to use) as well as adding a `GDK_BACKEND=x11` preset string to Wayland.

Comment: Are nautilus and gnome-terminal installed on the remote host?